# get request in web api null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I just started using web api and I was wondering if the parameter value is supposed to be `null` if you don't have any query parameters.

For example, I have this model:

```
[DataContract]
public class GetBooksRequest
{
    public int? BookLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Used in the following action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/books")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]GetBooksRequest request) {
  // request is null
}
```

Is parameter value supposed to be `null` if I hit `api/books`?.

It hits my endpoint, but parameter is `null`.  If I do `api/books?booklimit=1`, then parameter is not `null` and the `BookLimit` property is set to `1` as expected.

I just wasn't sure if that's the way web api works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is how it works. The framework inspects the request and will build up the model from the URI *(because it was told to check by [FromUri] attribute)*.

If it cannot build the model with the provided information the model/parameter will be set to its default value, in this case `null`. That is by design.

Source: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> **Using [FromUri]**
>
> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the
>   **[FromUri]** attribute to the parameter. The following example defines a GeoPoint type, along with a controller method that gets the
>   GeoPoint from the URI.
>
> ```
> public class GeoPoint
> {
>     public double Latitude { get; set; } 
>     public double Longitude { get; set; }
> }
>
> public ValuesController : ApiController
> {
>     public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> The client can put the Latitude and Longitude values in the query
>   string and Web API will use them to construct a GeoPoint. For example:
>
> ```
> http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989
> ```